# Help understanding marching squares algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

In my game, I want to layout squares along the edges of a monochrome image:
[image]

So I found this algorithm which should solve the issue.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares

It does not seem that hard to implement, I just think I do not understand exactly what Wiki is saying. I think I have to break the image up into cells where each cell represents 2x2 pixels on the image? Is that correct? I'm then lost by this instruction:

For each cell in the contouring grid:

1.Compose the 4 bits at the corners of the cell to build a binary index: walk around the cell in a clockwise direction appending the bit to the index, using bitwise OR and left-shift, from most significant bit at the top left, to least significant bit at the bottom left. The resulting 4-bit index can have 16 possible values in the range 0-15.

I'm not sure how to appending the bit.

Thanks

Comment: Marching squares is *not* what you want, despite its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the 2x2 cells, for each one you compute a number like this:

- set the number to 0
- if the top left point is above the threshold, add 8
- if the top right point is above, add 4
- if the lower right point is above, add 2
- if the lower left point is above the threshold, add 1.

Edited formatting.